# Does yaml-cpp license applies to organizations?

Tags: yaml-cpp

I'd like to use yaml-cpp for a project in my company. This project is part of a machine that will be sold to customers

The license file provided in 0.5.3 give permission to "any person obtaining a copy", but what about companies/organizations who would want to use it ?

Is this license applicable to companies?

Or do you recommend not to use yaml-cpp in this context ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking a legal question and not a programming question. For legal advice, consult an attorney licensed to practice in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Well, the question is directed to the owner of the yaml-cpp library (Jesse Beder), who is the one providing the license file. It's not a programming question, but the github project says that any question related to yaml-cpp  should be asked here.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the github project says. Questions related to the *use* (programming related) are appropriate here; questions regarding the licensing are not. My local fast-food restaurant can put *Comment to us on SO* on their website, too, but those comments would be off-topic here despite the fact that they said otherwise. There's a [Meta post about vendor support questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/62576) in the FAQ that says that regardless of what the vendor or project says, questions still have to meet the guidelines here in order to be on-topic.

Comment: Agreed with @KenWhite; SO is great for questions about the library, but this is a legal question. The license for yaml-cpp (the MIT license) is very commonly used, and any lawyer will be able to advise you on its meaning. Despite being the owner of the library, I'm not a lawyer, and cannot give you legal advice.